# How to create a jar from part of my project that is packaged as a war

Tags: java, maven, jar

I'm a Maven newbie, so I apologize if this is something trivial. Basically, I am developing a webapp, and I am using Maven to manage the project. I have `<packaging>war</packaging>` in my pom.xml so that that when I run `mvn package`, it will spit out a war file to deploy on the web server.

Now, as part of this application, we are using a 3rd party library that is delivered to us as a war and it is deployed separately on the web server. This war includes some custom integration functionality that we code up. For the persistence logic, I originally just wrote up a repository straight in this integration code. As I find I'm needing more persistence logic (more than basic SELECTs), I'm finding I'm wanting to use repositories and domain objects found in our application code. So, ideally, I would like to be able to jar up our core packages, and then include that jar in this 3rd party war so I have the same functionality available to me there.

I just don't know how I could set up the pom.xml to tell it what packages I would want in this jar (or even just 1 package if necessary), and how to create the jar itself. Is there a way to generate a jar from specific packages in a project that's setup to package the whole project as a war?

I found information about the [Maven jar plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/usage.html), but it says, "If the packaging of your project is set to 'jar', this plugin is executed whenever it passes the "package" phase." The packaging in my project is not set to jar. Is there still some way to use this plugin?

Comment: A .jar == a binary .war == a .zip file.  Same file format (Zip compression), different file contents.  So yes, you can definitely package your .war.  With Eclipse or NetBeans (how I usually do it), with [Ant](http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/java/sample-ant-build-script-create-war-file) or, in your case, with [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/). Just check the Ant and/or Maven links I cited.

Comment: Right, but I don't want everything that's in the war in the jar. I just want some specific java packages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a multi module project where one module contains your domain classes and the other module is your web application. By doing so your external 3rd party `war` can use your domain classes by just include that `jar`.

This is a simple overview of the directory structure:

```
.
├── pom.xml
├── domain
|   ├── pom.xml
|   └── src
|       └── main
|           └── java
|               └── com
|                   └── stackoverflow
|                       └── domain
|                           ├── SomeDao.java
|                           └── AnotherDao.java
└── web
    ├── pom.xml
    └── src
        └── main
            ├── java
            |   └── com
            |       └── stackoverflow
            |           └── web
            |               └── SomeBackingBean.java
            └── webapp
                └── WEB-INF
                    └── web.xml
```

### pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>Q12576767</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</name>

    <modules>
        <module>domain</module>
        <module>web</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- Inter-Module dependencies -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
                <artifactId>Q12576767-domain</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

### domain/pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>Q12576767</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>Q12576767-domain</artifactId>

    <name>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</name>
</project>
```

### web/pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>Q12576767</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>Q12576767-web</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>Q12576767-domain</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

By doing it this way you decouple some dependencies and can reuse the `jar` file from the `domain` module.

---

Also at the end you can look at using [Overlays](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html) to just create one `war` by overlaying the 3rd-party `war` with your own `war`. I don't know if it is feasible in your setup but it is worth looking at. I have sucessfully used it.

Comment: Like Metalhead, great answer. Totally agree with you.

Comment: @Jean-RémyRevy Thanks. I realize that I edited my answer at the same time as you did some edits and now yours disappeared. You can reapply them again.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think you can create a jar file from some packages because pom file belongs to one java/web project and not for individual packages in java project. You can create a new java project named e.g xyz-common which should have the code which will be shared with other war files. Then you can simple do mvn install and your xyz-common jar will be created with some version. Then update the pom file of the war file which needs your common jar with its dependency.

I assume your java packages are inside the war file? If so, better create a new java project and don't tightly couple your java code with war file. In your war file, just mention the dependency of your jar file.

Comment: Totally agree with you Metalhead ! DNC253 > Try to explode your classes in an another project, and make as much project as you need (three here).

Answer (score 0):

Use maven-jar-plugin, see :

- http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/usage.html

Example:

```xml
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                             <include>**/service/*</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>make-a-jar</id>
                <phase>compile</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>jar</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention what I found with that. See my updated question above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to generate the project with the `mvn archetype:generate` command? It builds you a fully working project structure for webapps with war packaging:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-webapp -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp
```

Comment: Well, I've got a war generating just fine. In addition to that, I want to be able to create a jar from some specific java packages to use in the 3rd party integration.