# Maven: generating a WAR of the whole project, and a JAR of a specific package

Tags: java, maven

I develop a webapp using a model-view-controller pattern. The `model` package represents the core API of the application, that could be used independently. The `controller` and `view` packages use the `model` package to produce a webapp.

**Question:** 
I'd like to be able to build a JAR of only the `model` package, and a WAR of the three packages. And I'd like to keep the three packages in a same project. The webapp WAR would include supplementary libraries as compared to the standalone JAR.
How could I achieve this with Maven? Would there be a solution using for instance two separate pom.xml files? (because as far as I know, you cannot choose two `packaging` options in the pom.xml)

(I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576767/how-to-create-a-jar-from-part-of-my-project-that-is-packaged-as-a-war), but I really want my three packages to be part of a same project, and be part of the same directory.)

Also, my project uses a classical webapp structure (simplified here):

```
my-app
-- pom.xml
-- src
----- main/
-------- java/
----------- model/
----------- view/
----------- controller/
-------- webapp/
---------- WEB-INF/
-------------classes/
```

Could I manage to generate the JAR in the classical `target/` directory, and the webapp in the classical `src/main/webapp/` directory? (and, as asked, including different libraries)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/).

With it you can have as many different *Assembly Descriptors* as you need, each one customized with its own *packaging scheme*, *filesets* and *dependencies*.

---

Here is a sample plugin configuration for your **pom.xml**:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
            <descriptors>
               <descriptor>src/main/assembly/model.xml</descriptor>
            </descriptors>
        </configuration>
     </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

And a sample assembly descriptor for the **model** jar (`src/main/assembly/model.xml`)

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
  <id>model</id>
  <formats>
    <format>jar</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/model</directory>
      <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
      <includes>
        <include>**/*</include>
      </includes>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Running `mvn clean package assembly:single` will generate both the standard **my-app.war** file from your project **pom.xml** and a **my-app-model.jar** in the target package.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into it, but it looks to be what I need. Could you provide an example of the configuration needed in my case? (or you can tell me to do my work myself ^^)

Comment: Wow, great, thank you ! (no reputation enough to upvote you :/)

Comment: Well, how do I include only some specific libraries?

Comment: Declare them as normal dependecies for the war project and [exclude unnecessary artifacts](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/single/including-and-excluding-artifacts.html) in the assembly descriptor.

Comment: Glad to be of service. Don't forget to accept either @Jintian or my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think you will prefer "war" as the default packing for the project and a more simple way do this is using maven-jar-plugin:

```
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.4</version>
           <executions>
               <execution>
                   <phase>package</phase>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>jar</goal>
                   </goals>
                   <configuration>
                       <classifier>weibo4j</classifier>
                       <includes>
                           <include>model/**</include>
                       </includes>
                   </configuration>
               </execution>
           </executions>
       </plugin>
```

Comment: Looks also like a great solution for my specific case, while Antony's solution provides a higher modularity. Thanks to both of you.